# Flyover list with vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a flyover menu. I need to control it's height to max 500px and set a scroll if it exceeds it. But unable to do so with the following code. The secondary fly menu just not shows up. Kindly suggest solutions to achieve the results.

```html
  
<div class="outlet-account-list" id="outlet-filtering" ng-show="showOutletFlyer">
 
 <style type="text/css">
  
  /** Top Level Menu **/

   #menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       list-style:none;
   }
   #menuwrapper ul{
    padding: 5px 0;
       background: #fff;
       width:170px;
       max-height: 500px;
   }
   #menuwrapper > ul {
    margin-left: 8px;
    overflow-x: visible; //Removing these two overflow rules will show up the list.
    overflow-y: auto;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li{
       width:100%;
       cursor:pointer !important;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul > li:hover{
       background-color:#e9f3ff;
       position:relative;
       cursor:pointer !important;

   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li a{
       padding:5px 10px;
       padding-right: 5px;
       color:#000;
       display:inline-block;
       text-decoration:none;
       width: 100%;
     cursor:pointer !important;
   }
   #menuwrapper ul li a span{
    cursor:pointer !important;
   }

   /**** SECOND LEVEL MENU ****/
  
   #menuwrapper ul li ul{
       position:absolute;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #ccc;
       display:none;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li:hover ul{
       left:166px;
       top:0px;
       display:block;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover{
       background-color:#e9f3ff;
   }

   #menuwrapper ul li ul li a{
       color:#000;
       display:inline-block;
       width:120px;
   }
   #menuwrapper ul{
       /*height: 500px;*/
       /*overflow-y: auto;*/
       /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
   }

   #menuwrapper ::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 4px;
   }

   #menuwrapper ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
       background-color: #000;
       -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   }
  
 </style>
 
       
 <div id="menuwrapper" ng-if="(outlets.length > 1 || outlets[0].accountCommands.length > 1)" ng-click="preventClick($event)">
     <ul>
         <li ng-if="outlets.length > 1"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc('','')" class="text-capitalize">All Outlets</a></li>
         <li ng-repeat="outlet in outlets" ng-click="(outlet.accountCommands.length == 1) && setOutletAcc(outlet.id,outlet.accountCommands[0].id)">
          <a><span class="pull-left wrap_text130 text-capitalize">{{outlet.name}}</span>
           <span class="icon-pagination-right pull-right marginTR5" ng-hide="outlet.accountCommands.length == 1"></span>
          </a>
             <ul ng-hide="outlet.accountCommands.length == 1">
                 <li ng-if="outlet.accountCommands.length>1"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, '')" class="text-capitalize">All Accounts</a></li>
                 <li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
        
       
     </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solved your issue. Right now I have added 100px height to show you scroll. later you can increase it to 500px.
check out the snippet

```css
/** Top Level Menu **/

   #menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       list-style:none;
   }
   #menuwrapper ul{
    padding: 5px 0;
       background: #fff;
       width:170px;
       max-height: 500px;
   }
   #menuwrapper > ul {
    margin-left: 8px;
    overflow-x: visible; //Removing these two overflow rules will show up the list.
    overflow-y: auto;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li{
       width:100%;
       cursor:pointer !important;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul > li:hover{
       background-color:#e9f3ff;
       position:relative;
       cursor:pointer !important;

   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li a{
       padding:5px 10px;
       padding-right: 5px;
       color:#000;
       display:inline-block;
       text-decoration:none;
       width: 100%;
     cursor:pointer !important;
   }
   #menuwrapper ul li a span{
    cursor:pointer !important;
   }

   /**** SECOND LEVEL MENU ****/
  
   #menuwrapper ul li ul{
       position:absolute;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #ccc;
       display:none;
              max-height:100px;
              overflow:auto;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li:hover ul{
       left:166px;
       top:0px;
       display:block;
   }
   
   #menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover{
       background-color:#e9f3ff;
   }

   #menuwrapper ul li ul li a{
       color:#000;
       display:inline-block;
       width:120px;
   }
   #menuwrapper ul{
       /*height: 500px;*/
       /*overflow-y: auto;*/
       /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
   }

   #menuwrapper ::-webkit-scrollbar {
       width: 4px;
   }

   #menuwrapper ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
       background-color: #000;
       -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="outlet-account-list" id="outlet-filtering" ng-show="showOutletFlyer">
 
 
       
 <div id="menuwrapper" ng-if="(outlets.length > 1 || outlets[0].accountCommands.length > 1)" ng-click="preventClick($event)">
     <ul>
         <li ng-if="outlets.length > 1"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc('','')" class="text-capitalize">All Outlets</a></li>
         <li ng-repeat="outlet in outlets" ng-click="(outlet.accountCommands.length == 1) && setOutletAcc(outlet.id,outlet.accountCommands[0].id)">
          <a><span class="pull-left wrap_text130 text-capitalize">{{outlet.name}}</span>
           <span class="icon-pagination-right pull-right marginTR5" ng-hide="outlet.accountCommands.length == 1"></span>
          </a>
             <ul ng-hide="outlet.accountCommands.length == 1">
                 <li ng-if="outlet.accountCommands.length>1"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, '')" class="text-capitalize">All Accounts</a></li>
                 <li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li>
                  <li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li><li ng-repeat="acc in outlet.accountCommands"><a ng-click="setOutletAcc(outlet.id, acc.id)" class="text-capitalize">{{acc.accountName}}</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
        
       
     </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The scroll needs to be on both lists. Will it work ?

Comment: The second list for sure is not a problem to add a scroll but first is.

Comment: for first list is also not a problem. scroll will come in first also. but that time second will not come proper. you should use jquery for that

Comment: You mean by setting `#menuwrapper > ul` to `overflow: auto` will make it scrollable. Have you tried it yourself.

Comment: yes I have tried. but if you do it like overflow:auto , then your second level will not visible. because its coming inside first level. then if you use position absolute also it will not work properly.

Comment: Yes I know that and that's the problem I posted. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: if you want scroll in first level than you should use jquery. CSS its not possible